# Android Studio cursor display error

Tags: android, android-studio, insert, cursor

My Android Studio gone strangely.

The cursor show normal when the Insert on.

And It show bold like the image show when the Insert off.

It's opposite to normal.

[image]

Comment: Well, as long as it works... Is it doing the same on other software?

Comment: Other software don't need Insert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press keyboard key "INSERT"
Cursor Bold On-Off

Answer (score -1):

Enter your keyboard

Press: Ins

Than solve your problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since [another user already posted that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612863/3169238). If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation